# How to read user defined object returned from JNI call

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

Below I have some method in java

```
public static Player getPlayer(String playerName);
```

Player is a user defined class in java.
Using JNI i want to read Player object in c++. From [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI) I learnt the basics of JNI calls. But I don't know how to read user defined objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're having trouble with. Somehow you need to get a reference to the `Player` _class_; either by calling `FindClass` or `GetObjectClass`. Once you have that class reference you can use `GetMethodID` and `GetFieldID` to get the IDs of the methods/fields of `Player` that you're interested in. And the final thing you need is an instance of `Player`, which it seems that you can get by calling `getPlayer` using `CallStaticObjectMethod`.

Comment: yes, I have used the GetFieldID, GetMethodID. Now its working. Thanks